# Is it possible to receive money from the IRS with someone else's bank details?

Tags: irs, covid-19, stimulus

As an expat living in Sweden I would like to claim my CARES stimulus money. I am (legally) a non-filer and would like to submit my bank details to the IRS so that they can send my CARES stimulus check money that I qualify for.

Unfortunately I do not have access to a US bank account and have tried creating one with TransferWise but they do not accept my Swedish ID.

If I give a friend's bank details in the form of a "routing number" and "account number", will the money be received, or will the transfer be rejected because the name doesn't match the account?

Comment: I know you said you are a non-filer, but have you ever filed and gotten a refund while you were in Sweden?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep no, I'm the child of a US citizen and have never lived in the US. I've also never earned over $12k as I am a student

Comment: As a student are you considered a dependent?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep no, I have no living people who would claim me as such

Comment: "If I give a friend's bank details" ... Cameron, you mean a friend *in the US* ?

Comment: Since comments are for tangnetially related points :)  ofx often works when transferwise doesn't, just because they're so much bigger.  But note , that solution will NOT work here.

Comment: Since it's already October, you might be better off waiting until filing season and getting it then. (Technically it's a refundable tax credit, and the payments they sent out are advance estimated refunds of that credit.) For a refund on a filed return, you still have the (deprecated) option of getting a paper check -- if you can negotiate such a check where you are.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you the exact answer: unfortunately it is 50/50.

I've dealt with precisely the issue of "different/incorrect account name" zillions of times, and the unfortunate fact is sometimes it sails through (which can either be a disaster or a good thing!) and sometimes it gets stopped.

Unfortunately that's the situation.

---

However, I'd say in this case, do not try this trick, as they will be highly pissed-off if they find out.

---

Note that the US' IRS is **really good** about stuff like this.

Phone them. They will sort it out. They're totally in to resolving "difficult money transfer issues". You'll have no problem at all.

Comment: This change from the French treasury which will typically refuse to send funds to a foreign bank or a bank without a branch through ɪʙᴀɴ discrimination (resulting in the funds being handed over through a French check).